# Measuring energy usage of smart contract execution

Tags: mining

Looking into measuring the energy consumption to me of executing particular smart contracts when mining, any tips on how to go about this?

Comment: Your question need to be more clear: can you detail it better?

Comment: What are you counting as mining? Are you talking about the thread/goroutine that pulls transactions from the transaction pool and checks they are valid (by running them)? Are you also counting the validation of received blocks (which involves running the transactions and therefore smart contracts)?

Comment: Also, I think this would probably require code alteration to stop the PoW Ethash algorithm from running at the same time. Then you'd need a way to monitor threads/goroutines (depending on which client).

Answer (score 2):

Thats almost impossible to get right in a network. Even if you would get some value, its just a rough estimate. You need to track all miners in the network, get the computing power, guess their energy consumption based on that (different graphic cards, different energy consumption) in total, assess this globally consumed (!) energy in kilowatts against different prices (different currencies in different regions). Then you need to get this "price" for the mining of just 1 block in the network (blocktime differs slightly, you need some average), divide the price by the numer of transactions in the block, maybe even compare it to the gas used in total. And I'm sure I've forgotten a ton of stuff just until this point...